# runlevel misunderstanding

Tags: upstart, init, runlevel

As I known there is no classical **init** in ubuntu, instead of **init** ubuntu uses **upstart**. Upstart is capable of fully simulation of classical **init**.

The problem is I still don't understand how **upstart** known which **runlevel** to boot now. For example, when I run ubuntu desktop how it knows that it needs to run **runlevel** for **X** and when I run ubuntu server how it knows to run **runlevel** for Single-User Mode.

As I know there are different folders for each runlevel **rc** x.**d**, do you know what "rc" stands for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) is an event-based replacement for the /sbin/init daemon which handles starting of tasks and services during boot, stopping them during shutdown and supervising them while the system is running.

rc is the command line interpreter for Unix.

rc file: Script file containing startup instructions for an application program (or an entire operating system), usually a text file containing commands of the sort that might have been invoked manually once the system was running but are to be executed automatically each time the system starts up.

<sup>Source:Linux Guide/Linux Dictionary V 0.16</sup>

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, do you know the answer to the 1st part of the question, how ubuntu knows that booting the desktop version it needs to start runlevel for x and etc?